# TFS drop location for this build was empty

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am getting the above error but my drop folder is populated within my TFS build work activity.
I also have the 'Copy outputs to build' set to YES.

Any reason why I could get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was due to my mis-understanding of TFS. If you retry a new build instead of queuing a new one, then of course it will use the cached properties of the 1st failed build with the wrong properties.